# How to set foreign key contraint name generated by hibernate on a linking table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to let `hibernate` create sql base on the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class MyBaseEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEmbeddable id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "mybaseentity_mymode", //sets the linking table name
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_param1", referencedColumnName = "param2"), //@Id param
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pram2", referencedColumnName = "param2")}, //@Id param
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_myembeddable_id")) //the contraint name
    private Set<MyModes> modes;
}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddable {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
}

@Entity
public class MyMode {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String code;
}
```

Each `MyBaseEntity` can have multiple modes. And the same `MyMode` can be linked to multiple base entities.

Question: how can I define the generated name of `CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE` inside the autogenerated linking table?

So far I used `@JoinTable` and two `@JoinColumn` definitions to set the constraint of the `@EmbeddedId` reference. But the foreign key constraint name reference to `MyMode` entity is still autogenerated.

Resulting sql so far with auto generated names:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mybaseentity_mymode
(
  mybaseentity_param1 character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  mybaseentity_param2 character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  modes_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mybaseentity_mymode_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mybaseentity_param1, mybaseentity_param2, modes_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk9tr9k9gtbqcpvoxfv2hqop6ta FOREIGN KEY (modes_id)
      REFERENCES public.mymode (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_myembeddable_id FOREIGN KEY (fk_param1, fk_param2)
      REFERENCES public.mybaseentity (param1, param2) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Answer (score 4):

We define custom ForeignKey constraints by following way
You can use `@ForeignKey(name="something_something")` for this purpose.

And you are defining `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne` mappings you can also use `@ForeignKey` embedded in  `@JoinColumn` like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "your_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "something_something"))
```

And for `@ManyToMany` relations you can use `uniqueConstraints`, `foreignKey` and `inverseForeignKey` embedded in `@JoinTable`

However, I am not sure it will work the way you want to define your constraints.

Comment: And how could I create a `ForeignKey` mapping of the key itself consists of two pks? (like the `@EmbeddedId` here `mybaseentity_param1, mybaseentity_param2`)?

Comment: Please see my update above. I could name one of the constraints using `@JoinTable` and `@JoinColumn`. But how could I name the remaining one?

Answer (score 1):

Solution as follows: the 2nd constraint is set by using the `inverse*` parameters.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "mybaseentity_mymode", //sets the linking table name
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_param1", referencedColumnName = "param2"), //@Id param   
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pram2", referencedColumnName = "param2")}, //@Id param
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_myembeddable_id"), //the contraint name
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_mode", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_mode_id"))
private Set<MyModes> modes;
```